# Regex with optional character

Tags: php, regex

I am working on a regex (for php) to match this kind of tag :

- {€orientation:landscape:foo:bar}
- {€orientation:landscape:foo}
- {€orientation:landscape}
- {€orientation}

I have actually this harcodred regex that work only for the 2nd tag

```
/{€([\da-zA-Z_-]+:[\da-zA-Z_-]+:[\da-zA-Z_]+)}/
```

Comment: Thanks for helping

Comment: Do you mean you need to validate the strings? Like with [`^{€([\da-zA-Z_-]+(?::[\da-zA-Z_-]+)*)}$`](https://regex101.com/r/YbYE6D/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a single-pass regex to get separate `:` separated values from inside `{...}`:

```
preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!\A):|{€(?=[^{}]*}))\K[\da-zA-Z_-]+~u', $s, $result)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9oq3SF/1)

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!\A):|{€(?=[^{}]*}))` - the end  of the previous successful match with a `:` after it (the `\G(?!\A):` part) OR (`|`) an opening brace with `€` after it, and then there must be `}` after 0+ chars other than `}` (see `(?=[^{}]*})` lookahead)
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `[\da-zA-Z_-]+` - (the actual match returned) 1 or more letters, digits, `_` or `-` symbols

Comment: wow, **this** is a regex ^^. Seems to fit perfectly why i need. Thks guy

Comment: Actually, the whole task can be simplified greatly using a 2-step approach: 1) use `preg_match_all('~{€[^{}]*}~u', $s, $result)` 2) explode all the matches with `:`.

Comment: which one is faster ?

Comment: I would go for the 1-regex approach, but most people usually complain it is not that readable.

Comment: btw, @Wiktor you are a regex god like

Answer (score 0):

The part of the string starting with `:` should be repeated 0 - n times, am I right?

It can be done with this

```
\{\€([\da-zA-Z_-])+(\:[\da-zA-Z\_\-]+)*\}
```

Second part of the regexp (`(\:[\da-zA-Z\_\-]+)*`) says "group starting with colon followed by sequence of numbers, characters, underscores and dashes longer than one character should be repeated from 0 to n times in string".

You can play with it [here](http://regexr.com/3fh9p).

Comment: * each word without the ":"